# Installing Sitecore 9.3 + SXA using SIA - not in default physical root

Tags: sxa, sitecore-install-assistant

I tried installing Sitecore 9.3 (simple developer machine setup) with the Sitecore Install Assistant. 
I checked SXA to be installed.

In the config file (`setup.exe.config`) all parameters were set correctly and I added one more to install in a physical folder of my choice:

`<parameter name="SitePhysicalRoot" value=".....\wwwroot" />`

This worked perfectly for Sitecore, but when SXA was installed I got an error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RootDirectoryPath'. Path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot.....' does not exist

So apparently the SXA installation is looking for the default path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the SitePhysicalPath is transferred en used in all of Sitecore jsons, but not in the one from SXA.

Quick fix: open `SXA-XP0.json` and find the `Site.PhysicalPath` variable (line 69). Adjust it to the path you installed the site, something like:

```
"Site.PhysicalPath": "[joinpath(environment('SystemDrive'), '...', '...', 'wwwroot', parameter('SiteName'))]"
```

A more elegant solution would be to add a parameter and use that one. To get the  required json you should check how it is done for IdentityServer (or xconnect or Sitecore):

- Add the parameter in the `sxa-XP0.json`
- Replace the variable in `sxa-XP0.json` with a check for the parameter (copy the code from identityserver.json)
- Add the parameters in `SXA-SingleDeveloper.json` just as it was done in XP0.SingleDeveloper.json (you will have 2 - the actual parameter and a reference with `SXA:` prefix)
- Add the parameter in setup.exe.config in the SXAXPSingle template section just as it was done in the XPSingle template